# Android Notification default for Vibrate,Led,Sound

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have build a sms Service Application now I wish to display notification on Receiving SMS in which I wish to use dafault means on device(Mobile Device) based setting i.e. if one select Vibration then Vibrate or if one select LED then `Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS` or if one select Sound or ring then `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND`.
Is it possible sir please help me in this regards or sorry for my bad English or not understand. I also tag my code below

```
private void displayNotification(String msg)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this.context,ZigbeeActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("ID", ID);
    i.putExtra("msg",msg);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(0,"Receiving SMS",System.currentTimeMillis());
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "SMS", msg, pendInt);     
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.icon = R.drawable.notify;     
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |     Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;          
    notif.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 1500;                         
    notif.ledOffMS = 1500;      
    nm.notify(ID, notif);
}
```

Comment: take a look at the Android documentation for notification for this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html. clarify what is not working in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS flag set. You shouldn't set it.
This code works for me

```
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
    notification.ledOnMS = 500;
    notification.ledOffMS = 500;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```